# Problem in alignment in tabulate module python

Tags: python, alignment, tabulate

Here is the code and output I am getting ,it is very much misaligned

```
sqlp="\nSELECT * FROM participants"
sqlsp="SELECT * FROM participants where ID=%s"
h=["Student ID","Name","School Name","Grade","Score"]
print(tabulate(data,headers=h,tablefmt="github",stralign="left",numalign="left"))
```

Output:
[Output of the tabulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wohNh.png)

Please help me to solve it

Comment: It just looks like you're using a proportional font instead of a monospaced font. Try using something like Consolas, Droid Mono, Cascadia Code, Courier New, or anything with "mono" in the name.

Comment: Thank you very much Chris It worlked all right